# How to prevent hashed password login in Tomcat 7.0.52?

Tags: apache, tomcat, hash, cryptography, webserver

I am using a Tomcat 7.0.52 server and using a hashed password in the tomcat-users.xml.

My server is accepting logins using the plain-text password and hashed password both.

How do I prevent / block users from logging in using the hashed password and force them to use the plaintext password?

Snippet of the following files

web.xml :

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
<realm-name>testvalue</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" digest="SHA"/>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<user username="testuser" password="xxxx--------------yyyy" roles="testrole"/>
```

Comment: A digest is a hash. Unclear what you're asking, and off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this isn't strictly the answer to what you asked but I would recommend upgrading tomcat to at least the latest version of 8.0 (8.0.48 at the time of posting).  It's been a while since I made the upgrade from 7 to 8 but if memory serves it was pretty painless.  [This link](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Migrating_from_7.0.x_to_8.0.x) should have everything you need to know about migrating up.  Only thing that comes to mind that you'll really need to look out for is it requires java 7 or higher and even that shouldn't be a big issue unless you have a particularly particular setup going.

Tomcat **8.0.x** Instructions Below

This is how I have mine set up and I cannot login by pasting my hashed password into the password field. I opted for sha-512 and arbitrarily picked 512 for my salt-length as well. You don't *have* to but why not?

Tomcat 8 - server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- Tomcat comment stuff trimmed out here -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase">
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="sha-512" saltLength="512" />
    </Realm>
</Realm>
```

Tomcat 8 - tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="yourrolehere"/>
<user username="yourusername" password="yourhashedpasswordhere" roles="yourrolehere"/>
```

I'm sure you already know how to use digest.bat (or digest.sh if that's your thing) but for anyone else tuning in open a command prompt and navigate to your tomcat installation and into the bin directory.  Then enter the following:

```
digest -a sha-512 -s 512 youRcl3artextpa$sword
```

This will produce a very long password hash in the format of:

```
youRcl3artextpa$sword:hashedpasswordforalongtime
```

Copy everything after the semi-colon and make sure it has no line breaks.  (clean it up in notepad if you need to) 
That's your new hashed password.

[Tomcat 8 Digested Passwords Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested_Passwords)